# Docker PostgreSQL Trust or Password

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, web-applications

I have a Docker stack that has a PostgreSQL container. This container is only accessed by other containers in its network, and it does not have any port published. So, my question is:

Can I just set `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust` or it would be a security risk and I should  set a password anyway?

Comment: When a hacker gets into your network, how are you going to stop this hacker? Without a password, you don't even try to prevent a data breach. But on the other hand, would that be a problem or not?

Comment: But, I thought that the Docker networks and containers were isolated. If I only expose one port of one frontend container, wouldn't the DB be secure?